# What's the default HTML font?

Tags: html, browser, fonts, default

Have a problem there, I was asked what font I used in my website, but the thing is that I didn't initialize any of it... What's the default font name I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not specify any font, then you did not really “use” any font. This would leave it to browsers to use their default fonts. The default font depends on the browser and on user settings. Traditionally, most browsers have used Times New Roman as the default font (or, on Mac platforms, Times), but nowadays many modern smallish devices often have browsers with other default fonts (e.g., Droid Sans in Android browser).

For a given browser, the situation can usually be determined by opening its tools for setting default fonts. Typically, a modern browser lets the user specify the type of font used as default (sans-serif, serif, monospace) and also specify for each type the default font of that type.

The situation is somewhat more complicated: If the page contains characters that have no glyphs in the default font, browsers are expected to use some substitute fonts for them, and modern browers generally do. But they apply different lists of fallback fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify any fonts, the browser will select a default font for you.  Generally, most browsers will generally default to "Times" (correction: not "Times New Roman")

Does your text look like this screenshot?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Mm72dpCMKlcUlkQzI0TlpzcHc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It is browser-dependant and is stored in the default css of the browsers. Firebug, js-debugger in explorer, or the embedded debuggers of other browsers can say it on a simple examination of a textual element on any simple (f.e. css-less) HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on  what browser you are using.If you also change the font style as well as other setting in the browser then That setting will be apply for the font.If you notice different hand hold devices uses different font size and font style like mobile vendor.

Answer (score -1):

This really depends on the browser. See here for a good list: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Answer (score -1):

When a website doesn't specify a font, each browser uses its own default font.

To find out what it is, go into the browser's settings and look at the font settings. My browsers all had Times New Roman as the default font. It might be different depending on the fonts installed on different computers.